# Finding if meeting point in graph exists

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Consider a Graph connecting various cities through railways. Every Node is a city which has various railway lines (edges) to reach the other city. You need to find if a meeting point exists i.e. one such route (i.e. sequence of lines) which when taken always arrives to the same city no matter from which city you start.

Eg.
Consider Graph G = [[2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1], [1, 0]]. The k^th element of Graph (counting from 0) will give the list of stations directly reachable from station k.

The outgoing lines are numbered 0, 1, 2... The r^th element of the list for station k, gives the number of the station directly reachable by taking line r from station k.

Then one could take the path [1, 0]. That is, from the starting station, take the second direction, then the first. If the first direction was the red line, and the second was the green line, you could phrase this as:
if you are lost, take the green line for 1 stop, then the red line for 1 stop.
So, consider following the directions starting at each

`0 -> 1 -> 2.`

`1 -> 0 -> 2.`

`2 -> 1 -> 2.`

`3 -> 0 -> 2.`

So, no matter the starting station, the path leads to station 2.

The limits for lines is from 0 to 5 and the limits for station is 2 to 50. So in the worst case there might be 2^(49*5) subsets of routes so brute force is out of the question.

Edit1 : 
After [mcdowella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240457/mcdowella) mentioned this problem being called `Synchronising sequences in DFAs`

Ans also, I am interested only **if a meeting path exists or not** I found out [this pdf](https://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/atc-2011/Raghu-DFA%20Synchronization.pdf) (slide 5) states that

```
Adler and Weiss, 1970 (Conjecture)
Every finite strongly connected aperiodic directed graph of uniform outdegree has 
a synchronizing coloring.
```

Alternatively,

```
Every strongly connected graph with 'x' cycles all having gcd 1 (which states 
aperiodicity) has a meeting path.
```

Which works for **most** cases. However, it's not hard to come up with something like this :

[image]

Which is neither strongly connected, so aperiodicity becomes out of question. And still has a meeting path [0 -> 1]. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you know the length of the path?

Comment: Do you mean the maximum length of meeting path? I've already mentioned it in the question. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Then I obviously misinterpreted some of the question. Here are my interpretations. Please correct them if they are wrong: *The limits for lines is from 0 to 5* -> Each sublist in G can have up to 5 entries. *limits for station is 2 to 50* -> there will be at most 50 sublists in G.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes you are correct. Alternatively : There are upto 50 nodes and each might have upto 5 outgoing edges

Comment: Ok, so what about the path length?

Comment: A single path can be as small as 2 and as large as 49*5  ( i. e. max  no of nodes - 1 times max. outgoing paths)

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the purpose of your image and example, but the conjecture you quote is of the form "if A then B" and your image and example appear to be of the form "Not A but still B". The example does not conflict with the quote, For that matter, it is not clear whether the quote guarantees a synchronizing path for every colouring or simply says that given a graph it is possible to colour the links so a synchronizing path exists. Perhaps if you can find the papers referenced on that page things will be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what to do if the path says to go out along x and there is no outgoing link labelled x, so I am going to suppose that all nodes have a full set of outgoing links, or we treat such missing links as links back to the current node, or copies of the link labelled 0, or something.

I start with a set of possible nodes that we may be on, initialised to the set of all nodes.

For each label, take the set of possible nodes and compute the set of nodes that you get by going from any node in the current set, following the current label, to another node. If, for each possible label, the result is always the same set as the current set of possible nodes, give up. This means that each label maps each node in the current set to a different node, and, given any node in the current set and any path, of whatever length, you can find a unique node in the current set with a path that ends in the chosen node, so the situation looks hopeless to me.

If, for some label, the set of nodes after applying this label to the current set is smaller than the current set, note down that label, make the new smaller set the current set, and repeat.

If this process terminates in a set of size one you have worked out a path that ends with that node a meeting point, and the path is no longer than the number of nodes in the original graph, since each step reduces the number of nodes in the graph by at least one. Each step costs you at most the number of edges in the graph, so for a graph with N nodes and K labels per node, the cost is at most KN^2.

In fact, since the check at each stage amounts to looking for at least one node in the current set with two incoming edges with the same label on it, and then removing all nodes in the current set which don't have an incoming edge with the chosen label, I would hope that you can make the cost at each step linear in the number of nodes discarded, and argue that the total cost is something below O(KN^2)

(I'm pretty sure that I have seen this worked out properly somewhere as an exercise in robot navigation or something so a web search might be more reliable than reading this, but I've had fun writing it, and it looks plausible to me).

Edit -

It appears that the problem is referred to as a search for synchronizing sequences for finite automata. math.uni.wroc.pl/~kisiel/auto/Homing.pdf looks very promising but I haven't gone through it in detail.

Comment: I've worked out on your algorithm,  but sometimes I end up with a single node before the actual meeting point comes.Eg if the answer is the path 1->2->3 then at a point the only current node left is 2.

Comment: I thought in the same direction and I fear it is not as simple as that. There may be cases when you need to map the current set to another set of the same size to be able to continue reducing the size. Therefore, it is not guaranteed that every step reduces the size by one (I have an example but formatting it in the comments is a bit tedious; I'm sure you can think of one). To me, this problem looks NP-complete.

Comment: @NicoSchertler indeed not, it has to stop at 3 and finding the meeting path is definitely NP Complete, but that's not the problem, we only need to find if a **meeting path exists or not**, probably by some observation like loops etc.

Comment: @MayurKulkami I made a simplifying assumption that we can pretend that every node has the same number of outgoing links, if necessary by fudging it e.g. by adding links to self. In this case 1->2->3->3 (I can't see a nice way of drawing loops) and the process appears to converge with the set {3}

Comment: It appears that the problem is referred to as a search for synchronizing sequences for finite automata. See e.g.  http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~kisiel/auto/Homing.pdf Algorithm 2 PDF P 10 finds such a sequence costed in Theorem 1.15 PDF P12 labelled P14 as polynomial in time and space (more detail there).

Comment: Thanks for naming the problem, now I can read many academic papers on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: There is an `O(n^2)` algorithm which determines if a meeting path *exists*, which is described here:

Consider `P(G)`, the power graph of the original graph `G`. The power graph is created by taking all subsets of the set of nodes of the original graph `G`, and making each of those subsets into nodes themselves. The edges connect nodes as follows:

(using `G = [[2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1], [1, 0]]`), and looking at the edge 1 (or line 1, as your problem states)

`{0, 1, 2} -> {1, 0, 1} = {0, 1}`, since, when taking line 1, `0 -> 1`, `2 -> 1`, `1 -> 0`.

`{0, 3} -> {1, 0}`, since, when taking line 1, `0 -> 1` and `3 -> 0`.

etc.

Now, if there are `n` stations, then, if there exists a path from the node `{0, 1, ..., n-1}` in `P(G)` to a singleton (set of one element) node in `P(G)`, there is a meeting point. Because, if you take that path as the series of lines, starting at any of the stations will end in the same station. Now, creating the powerset is of course very expensive (`O(2^n)`), but making an important remark causes the amount of computation to be `O(n^2)`.

This remark is very similar to that of (Černý, 1964) on the word synchronization problem of DFA's. A proof sketch of this remark is at the end this answer. The remark is that, when looking at the power graph of `G`:

*Every node representing a subset of size 2 has a path to a singleton node if and only if there exists a meeting path*

That is, when we create `P(G)`, we only need to create nodes that represent subsets of size 2 or less. This means that `P(G)` will have only `n^2` nodes.

**So, essentially the algorithm is**:

1. Create `P_2(G)`, the power graph of `G` where each node represents a subset of size 2 or less.
2. For each node representing a subset of size 2 in `P_2(G)`:
   If there is no path from this node to a singleton node, return `False`
3. return `True` (will only happen if, for every node representing a subset of size 2, there is a path to a singleton node).

Part 2 of the algorithm can be done with DFS: you can reverse all of the edges of `P_2(G)` and begin the DFS stack with all of the singleton nodes. Then, if the DFS tree contains all of the nodes representing subsets of size 2, then all of the nodes representing subsets of size 2 have a path to a singleton node.

Part 1 is `O(n^2)` and Part 2 can be done in `O(n^2)` by reversing the edges of the graph and performing DFS as described above.

I hope this has been mostly clear.

**Proof of the remark:**
We first treat the direction where, a meeting path exists implies that, for every node representing a subset of size 2, there is a path to a singleton node. Just take the meeting path. Since it's a meeting path, starting at any node in `G` ends up in the same node. So, taking the meeting path will reach a singleton node.

Now, if for every node representing a subset of size 2, there is a path to a singleton node: then, one can construct a meeting path. Take two different nodes representing subsets of size 2, name them `A` and `B`. Then, take `A`'s path to a singleton. Taking this path, `A -> {i}` and `B -> C`, For some `C` and `{i}`. Then, take `C`'s path to a singleton. `{i} -> {j}` and `C -> {k}`. Then, there is a meeting path for the node representing `{j, k}`. So, we can find a meeting path for the union of `A` and `B`. Thus, we can do this for any pair of nodes. Inductively, you can find a meeting path for the union of any set of nodes representing subsets of size 2, so this can be done until the entire set of nodes is the starting point and a singleton node is the end.

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in a comment on mcdowella's comment, I suspect this problem to be NP-complete. But a reasonable heuristic may allow you to get to the target in a reasonable time.

The following idea is based on A*. You represent the current set of stations as nodes (i.e. every set corresponds to one node). Since you have at most 50 stations, every step can be represented as a 64-bit number (where each number describes if the according station is in the set).

You want to maintain a list `O` of open nodes and a list `V` visited nodes. Start with `C` and `O` containing a single node that represents all stations.

The algorithm then has the following structure:

1. Choose the node in `O` with the least number of stations `-> n`.
2. Remove `n` from `O`.
3. For every line

   1. transform `n` to the set of stations `nt` that result from travelling from the stations in `n` with the specified line (and count the number of stations to speed things up).
   2. If `nt` has a single station, you have found a meeting point (there may be more than one)
   3. If `nt` has not been visited before, add it to `O` and `V` and set its path to the current path.
   4. If `nt` has already been visited, you have two choices. Either update the path of `nt` to achieve a path of minimal length or just ignore it.
4. Go to 1

The size of this graph is exponential in the length of the path. Therefore, this algorithm has exponential worst-case time and space complexity. However, since you always pick the node with the fewest stations, you take a step that is assumed to take you to the target on the fastest route. This may be a wrong step, which is why we need to keep the remaining graph. You will also calculate the graph on the fly, which avoids keeping the entire graph in memory (unless there is no solution).